# Programmatically Add edittext iD

Tags: java, android-edittext

I already know how to create edittext programmatically but the problem is they have the same Id, How can I add random Id on each edittext generated

Comment: declare one `static` inetegr and use some random `constant` string like 'edittext' and append that number to the string. And increment the number each time when you create new `EditText`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set a unique id for each view. Just set different tags for them:

```java
private static String getTag(int index) {
    return "MY_TAG_" + index;
}

...

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    EditText editText = new EditText(this);
    editText.setId(android.R.id.edit);  // same id
    editText.setTag(getTag(i));         // different tag
    layout.addView(editText);
}

EditText firstField = layout.findViewWithTag(getTag(0));
System.out.println(firstField);
```

But, if you still want to, there's a static method `View.generateViewId()`:

```java
int[] fieldIds = new int[3];

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    fieldIds[i] = View.generateViewId();
    EditText editText = new EditText(this);
    editText.setId(fieldIds[i]); // different id
    layout.addView(editText);
}

EditText firstField = layout.findViewById(fieldIds[0]);
System.out.println(firstField);
```

> I/System.out: android.widget.EditText{ed04adc VFED..CL. ......I. 0,0-0,0 #1020003 android:id/edit}

Comment: Even if you use `View.generateViewId()`, you just need to store the generated ids for later use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code for each id's `EditText`

```
View.generateViewId()
```